# Can't get an accurate temperature reading from a VMA320 thermistor on an ESP8266/NodeMCU

Tags: math, arduino, arduino-esp8266

I bought a couple of VMA320 thermistors at the electronics store the other day on a whim without having any idea what I was getting myself into. I've been at this for days and I just cannot figure out how to turn the data this thing is sending me into an accurate temperature reading. I've read several guides and tried using several sketches straight off the web, but I keep getting the same result. In a room that's around 70-72°F, I'm reading about 40°F (with the code for a "pull-up" configuration, which is what my thermistor is), or around 150°F (in the pull-down configuration). The raw data from the analog pin remains constant at around 750, which leads me to believe the problem must be the formula(s) I'm using (all based on the Steinhart-Hart equation).

The thermistor is designed to take in 5V, and it has a built-in 10k Ohm resistor. I get the above temp readings pretty consistently by getting the 5V from my ESP8266's VIN pin with the micro USB plugged in (although I've metered it and it's actually about 4.35V). I've also tried powering the thermistor instead with a 12V DC adapter + an adjustable buck converter tuned in to exactly 5V, but that gives me wildly inconsistent readings for unknown reasons. I figured I might be sending it too much voltage from the buck converter (because more voltage drop from the extra wires needed to test it with my multimeter?), so I tried slowly tuning the voltage down while reading the serial monitor to see if I could tweak it into a sane reading — no luck. And I have applied some mild heat to the thermistor and observed the temperature reading spike as expected, so I don't think the component is at fault.

I'm just about ready to give up on this project. I'm not great at math and I'm brand new to electronics, so truth be told I really don't understand the formulas I've been plugging into the code. Am I missing something obvious here? Do I need to adjust the formula to account for the 4.35 instead of 5V, and if so, how? Is it possible that the variables I'm using for the B coefficient and/or the nominal temperature are wrong, and if so, how do I find the correct values? The user manual for this component is pretty sparse, so the only things I know for sure are that it uses a 10k Ohm resistor and a pull-up configuration (whatever that means).

```
//---------------
byte NTCPin = A0;
#define SERIESRESISTOR 10000
#define NOMINAL_RESISTANCE 10000
#define NOMINAL_TEMPERATURE 25
#define BCOEFFICIENT 3950

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
    float ADCvalue;
    float Resistance;
    ADCvalue = analogRead(NTCPin);
    Serial.print("Analog value ");
    Serial.print(ADCvalue);
    Serial.print(" = ");
    //convert value to resistance
    Resistance = (1023 / ADCvalue) - 1;
    Resistance = SERIESRESISTOR / Resistance;
    Serial.print(Resistance);
    Serial.println(" Ohm");

    float steinhart;
    steinhart = Resistance / NOMINAL_RESISTANCE; // (R/Ro)
    steinhart = log(steinhart); // ln(R/Ro)
    steinhart /= BCOEFFICIENT; // 1/B * ln(R/Ro)
    steinhart += 1.0 / (NOMINAL_TEMPERATURE + 273.15); // + (1/To)
    steinhart = 1.0 / steinhart; // Invert
    steinhart -= 273.15; // convert to C
    steinhart = steinhart * 1.8 + 32; // convert to F

    Serial.print("Temperature ");
    Serial.print(steinhart);
    Serial.println("°F");
    delay(1000);
}
```

The code above (and all the other example sketches I've found) uses the Steinhart-Hart equation. If I'm understanding it correctly, what it's trying to do, ultimately, is calculate the difference in resistance between a resistor with a known value (10k Ohm) and the thermistor (which fluctuates based on temperature), by inferring it from the voltage returned, which is what the ADC value represents (mapped from 0 to 1023). I think. "If I'm understanding correctly" is a big if, lol. The last few lines are just converting the calculated resistance to temperature in Kelvin, then Celsius, then Fahrenheit.

Comment: This looks fishy on several instances. The first issue: Resistance is most probably to be a float ranging from 0..1. But you are *not* converting it to such. The ADC seems to deliver 0..1023, so this range must be mapped to 0..1. Ask yourself what you are doing with 1023/ADCvalue - 1 there. The line afterwards makes no sense to me either, but to really judge it I need to read the datasheet first.

Comment: Ok, forget my comment. The code I found does the same, and while I too struggle understanding this, it's probably just a compact formula to account for the inverted behaviour of the resistor - resistance goes *down* if the temperature goes up. Does the raw ADC value behave correctly regarding this?

Comment: The code above uses the Steinhart-Hart equation; I updated the post to reflect that. If I'm understanding correctly, what it's doing, ultimately, is calculating the difference in resistance between a resistor with a known value (10k Ohm) and the thermistor, by inferring it from the voltage, which is what the ADC value represents (mapped from 0 to 1023). I think. "If I'm understanding correctly" is a big if, lol. The last few lines are just covering the calculated resistance to temperature in Kelvin, then Celsius, then Fahrenheit.

Comment: And yes, the ADC value seems to behave as expected when exposing the thermistor to sudden changes in temperature.

Comment: The all I can think of is to carefully control that the values and computations match. I’m usually a python and C++ guy, so what would be wrong in those languages is the use of 1023 / adc. Because that’s integer division, so it’s always 1. Not a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ADC compares the input voltage to a reference voltage and outputs a corresponding value in its output range.
The reference voltage on simple chips is commonly the supply voltage, on many chips the adc has its own reference voltage, something to watch out for.

In your case, the ESP8266 looks to be a 3.3V chip, so you should connect the 5V on your VMA320 to the 3.3V on the ESP8266

The VMA320 just forms a resistor divider with the thermistor and reference resistor, so the actual supply voltage is not important and it will work just as well on 3.3V

Comment: @dannymcgee if you haven't seen it already, I recommend checking out [this link](https://arduinodiy.wordpress.com/2015/11/10/measuring-temperature-with-ntc-the-steinhart-hart-formula/)

Comment: That link is where I got the code from as posted in the question. What I did not understand is that the voltage from the thermistor was being interpreted relative to the **chip voltage**. The user manual for the VMA320 said 5V in, so I was determined to try to give it 5V. After feeding it 3.3V from the ESP8266, it's giving me an accurate reading without any code changes. Thank you so much!!